# C# - Can't find usage of method when inherited and used through an interface implemented by the subclass

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

I'm using VisualStudio 2008 and 2010, both with ReSharper, and when I try to lookup for usages of a given method I get no results, despite the method being inherited and then called through an interface. What's wrong? Is that a VS/ReSharper bug?
See the example below:

```
using System;
namespace UsageNotFound
{
   interface MyInterface
   {
       void Hello();
   }

   class SuperClass
   {
       public void Hello() //NOTE: VS 2008/2010 (with resharper)
seems unable to find usages on this!!!
       {
           Console.WriteLine("Hi!");
       }
   }

   class SubClass : SuperClass, MyInterface
   {
       public static MyInterface GetInstance()
       {
           return new SubClass();
       }
   }

   class Program
   {
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           SubClass.GetInstance().Hello();
       }
   }
}
```

Thanks,
  Fabrizio

Comment: Works for me (VS 2010 + ReSharper 6) and it gets the correct intellisense and compiles just fine.

Comment: @peer. You do not need to have an access modifier

Comment: Verified that it doesn't work for me either. With Resharper 5.1.

Comment: @user1022016, Ray: This is most likely a ReSharper 5.1 bug then. ReSharper 6 works fine.

Comment: @m-y the issue is not with intellisense or compilation. The issue is that Find Usages on the impl of `Hello` does not tell you about the invocation in `Main`

Comment: @AakashM: ReSharper 6/VS 2010 still gave me the correct info.

Comment: A side comment: You really shouldn't implement interfaces this way, the interface should be on the base class for obvious reasons.

Comment: @m-y interesting, I get no results from the same

Comment: @AakashM: Are we looking at the same thing? I just hover over the interface method Hello() and a popup box comes up, I click that and go to "References" and it shows me a list of all usages.

Comment: @m-y it finds usages of `MyInterface.Hello` correctly, but the bug is that it doesn't find any usages of `SuperClass.Hello`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4641/discussion-between-m-y-and-aakashm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue: http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/RSRP-46273 with no current target fix version

Comment: I've fixed this a couple of months ago =)

Answer (score 1):

Probably because your `SuperClass` doesn't implement the interface. This may cause a problem for ReSharper. Try:

```
   class SuperClass : MyInterface
   {
       public void Hello()
       {
           Console.WriteLine("Hi!");
       }
   }
```

Comment: Although I do agree that the base class should implement the interface, hence it's creating a function `Hello()` it isn't necessary to solve his issue. His issue might be involved with the VERSION of ReSharper?

Comment: I think the superclass doesn't conceptually need to implement the interface. The superclass could probably even be in a separate project (or library) altogether, and be completely decoupled from the interface.

Answer (score 0):

It's all to do with the order in which `SubClass` inherits the `Hello()` method from `SuperClass` and `MyInterface`.

I'm surprised that you don't get a warning that the `SubClass.Hello()` (from implementing the interface definition) will hide the `SuperClass.Hello()`.

Comment: I don't think there's any hiding: the implementation has to be explicitly provided, and it is provided in the base class. There's just one implementation of that method in that sample.